# How can I make my children components inherits a parent class method/state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a React application and I feel like I have a beginner question, but I can't seem to figure out an answer to it.

Basically, I am building a comparator for credit cards/savings accounts/etc. The pages are the same: I have an header, some filters, a sorting selection and finally "rows" to compare the result. I built this once but I need it 3 times. In this component, there are methods that I will reuse such as the call to get the financial institutions and I can reuse the call to get the differents options. However, I don't want to duplicate my code.

This brought me two options: I can either get these functions, put them in another file and import them or I can make other components inherit from one parent component.

The first option is great, but my methods change the state. If it is external to the component, it won't change the state. (and I don't want to do like var = x() for each call).

The second option would be perfect in other circumstances, but I heard that inheriting in React is bad. However, I feel like this is the only way I can reuse the methods to change the state.

Can you help me figure this out?

(I can give code since I am building this for a company and I can't reveal the code to everyone)

Comment: Why not use custom hooks?

Comment: Here's a generic explanation on the inheritance topic: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html
One solution could be having a container/wrapper component (like prototype) containing the common parts. Then you could use it with different children (special instances) or passing down different props overwriting the default methods.